# Почему ansible не использует конфигурацию ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

Рефакторю плейбук ansible.

Раньше в файле inventory для каждого хоста я хардкодил пользователя и ключ для ssh, а теперь хочу от этого уйти. Взамен этого ansible должен запускаться от любого пользователя и брать данные из `.ssh/config`:

Имя локального пользователя: `foo`

В конфиге (он нужен только потому, что учетки `foo` на хостах нет и не планируется):

```
Host staging
    HostName staging.server.domain
    User bar
```

На сервере публичный ключ пользователя `bar` добавлен в `authorized_keys`. Соединение проходит на ура:

```
$ ssh staging
Welcome to Ubuntu...    
bar@staging.server.domain:~$
```

Теперь то же самое в ansible:

В inventory:

```
[myservice-staging]
staging.server.domain
```

Напомню, что пользователя я намеренно не указываю, т.к. каждый должен логиниться со своими настройками (например, у сервера интеграции свой пользователь и ключ).

При запуске плейбука

```
fatal: [staging.server.domain] => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password).
    while connecting to 1.2.3.4:22
```

А вот такой inventory работает. Но меня это не устраивает, т.к. я захардкодил псевдоним хоста, а он не у всех такой в `.ssh/config`

```
[myservice-staging]
staging
```

Что я делаю не так? Как заставить ansible использовать нужное значение из `.ssh/config`, но не хардкодить псевдонимы хостов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как я понимаю, разница между подключениями к `staging` и `staging.server.domain` заключается в том, что в первом случае используется имя пользователя *bar* (благодаря содержимому `~/ssh/config`), а во втором — имя текущего пользователя.

чтобы и во втором случае использовалось имя *bar*, можно, например, добавить `staging.server.domain` в директиву *host* файла `~/ssh/config`:

```
host staging staging.server.domain
hostname staging.server.domain
user bar
```

---

**немного расшифровки**

весь файл `~/.ssh/config` состоит из набора секций. каждая секция начинается с «заголовка», с директивы:

```
host ...
```

и продолжается до следующей секции, начинающейся с такой же директивы.

кстати, у первой секции «заголовок» может отсутствовать. тогда подразумевается:

```
host *
```

т.е., для любого *имени*.

*имя* же мы указываем в параметрах программ `ssh`, `scp`, `rsync` и т.п., например:

```
ssh staging.server.domain
```

в этом случае, если с этим именем найдётся совпадение в «заголовке» одной из секций, то из этой секции будут взяты все упомянутые в ней параметры (hostname, port, user и т.д. и т.п.)

Comment: Так и оказалось. Но почему HostName это на самом деле URL и он указывается в единственном варианте, а Host - это как раз имя, и может иметь варианты? Не вижу в этом логики...

Comment: @NickVolynkin, внёс дополнение.

Comment: спасибо, так стало понятнее.